# Is it possible to search in all the content of files uploaded to SharePoint Server?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I wish to made available a functionality that searches in all pages and content inside all the documents (word, excel, pdf, etc.) present in our SharePoint Server 2007 that all the users uploaded.

Anyone could tell me if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the main selling points of SharePoint - that all content, whether pages or documents can be crawled, indexed and searched.

(Most) Office documents are indexed natively by SharePoint, whereas PDFs are an example of a file type that require an iFilter to be installed on the server in order to make the *contents* searchable.

May as well mention too that search results are security trimmed - users only see search results for content that they have permission to access.

Comment: Hi, Brian. Thanks for the quick answer. Is this available for WSS also or only for MOSS? In the 2007 version also? Thanks.

Comment: wss can only search the current site i believe. MOSS can search across site collections. so for any pratical search, you need MOSS Enterprise license.